# Let the user know that flagging a Question/Answer will cause you to automatically add a comment

Tags: feature-request

Basically, The feature that when you flag a post, it also posts a comment to said post detailing why you flagged it, has recently been added to the SE software.

This caught me a bit by surprise, as it changes the existing behaviour of the SE site, and I wound up having people respond to comments that I wasn't aware I posted.

I think it would be nice if there was some information somewhere in the flagging dialog that flagging the post will auto-add this comment.

---

<sup><sub>For that matter, can we get an explanation of what specific actions trigger this macro in the first place? Is it for every possible post flag, or only some of them?</sub></sup>

Comment: This has been in the software for quite a while, but I thought it was only through the review queue. I will let someone who knows offhand answer. The updates to the flagging system might have added it to the flag dialog also.

Comment: I am sure now, flagging does not add a comment, the action that does is taking part in the review queue. Flagging is intended to be much more private a task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Reviewing and flagging answers causes the forum software to automatically add a comment impersonating me?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/reviewing-and-flagging-answers-causes-the-forum-software-to-automatically-add-a/2689#2689)

The "recommend deletion" dialog is pretty clear about the fact that it will leave a comment on your behalf should you ask it to do so for you.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Huh. Well, I guess I'm lame.